# Is there a way to debounce the $digests (triggered by an external call)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I would like to debounce the digests of a huge angular app.

I have a lot of updates coming from http calls and I would like to avoid to trigger a digest each time but at most once per XXX ms.

By example, with this code :

### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
    counter value : {{ctrl.counter}} - Should be 100 at the end of the process <br>
    Digests count : <span id="digest-counter"></span> - Should be as low as possible
  </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
let digestsCounter = 0;

angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl', ($log, $timeout, $rootScope) => {

$rootScope.$watch(() => {
digestsCounter += 1;
document.getElementById('digest-counter').innerHTML = digestsCounter;
});
this.counter = 0;
for(let i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i) {
$timeout(() => {this.counter += 1}, 10 * i);
}

return this;
});
```

### I got at the end:

```
counter value : 100 - Should be 100 at the end of the process 
Digests count : 202 - Should be as low as possible
```

How can I debounce the digest to avoid the 202 digest ?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LmL25eLy/1/) with the previous code that illustrate my problem.

Comment: You can debounce a function that triggers digests with $digest or $apply, as any other function in JS. You can't suppress digests that are naturally triggered by services ($http, $timeout). Use non-Angular alternatives (axios, fetch) and native promises instead of $http and $q if you want to control digests manually.

Comment: You can try using `useApplyAsync` of the `$http` service. But anyway, if you want to make a less calls to `$digest` - then one way of doing this - is to change the data outside of angularjs context, and then call `$apply` manually like - https://jsfiddle.net/y4rpbyht/1/ (just an example for replacing `$timeout`)

Comment: hi @estus and Stanislav, thx for your feedbacks. I'm using [ng-redux](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux) in my application for the data handling from the http backend. So, I can't trigger the digest "on demand" :/

Comment: This totally depends on how it's done in your case, possibly specific to ng-redux (I'm not familiar with it). $http could be replaced with non-Angular requests that are orchestrated somehow to produce a single debounced digest, e.g. in Axios interceptor.

Comment: @estus I finally patched ngRedux to debounce the digest trigerred by ngRedux itself. Thx for your help guys.